# Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{(a-b)(-b)^{n-1}x^n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Here is the summation:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{(a-b)(-b)^{n-1}x^n}$$

Now, I tried

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|}$$

which eventually gave me

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left|\frac{-b}{x}\right|}=\left|\frac{-b}{x}\right|$$

So solving

$$\left|\frac{-b}{x}\right|<1$$

should give me the radius of convergence, right? But I tried solving it and I get a strange answer. The answer in the book is

> $$\frac{1}{\left|b\right|}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The limit should be $|bx|$. I don't know why you put the $x$ in the denominator

Comment: it is $\frac{1}{|b|}$ you made a small mistake.

Comment: @b00nheT because I'm really silly.

Comment: Nah. x above, x below, x goes somewhere I don't know. I've made plenty of similar mistakes. Don't get down on yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the quotient rule (Why? Beats me...but whatever):

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{(-b)^nx^{n+1}}{(-b)^{n-1}x^n}\right|=|bx|<1\iff |x|<\frac1{|b|}$$

With Cauchy-Hadamard formula:

$$\frac1R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|(-b)^{n-1}|}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{|-b|^n}}{\sqrt[n]{|-b|}}=|b|$$

The convergence radius is thus $\;R=\cfrac1{|b|}\;$

Comment: does $a_n$ contain  $x$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam No, of course not. $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is the sequence of coefficients of $\;(x-x_0)^n\;$ . It really bewilders me how many people don't know, or forgot, the great Cauchy-Hadamard formula (theorem) from power series :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of that method before even from two books. Our course apparently doesn't teach that method, but now I know about it and will use it, so thank you. But does it have any advantages? It seems like the "quotient rule" is a bit less involved in this case. Doesn't the $n \to \infty$ go under the $\text{lim sup}$ instead of the $\text{sup}$ as written in the Wikipedia article? Btw I fixed what seems to be a small mistake in the working

Comment: @SkeletonBow What books are you using!? And in this, and many other, cases it has a huge advantage: less stuff in the limit, way smoother and cleaner, simpler. Not always, though.

Comment: @DonAntonio the books are for a specific high school course, so I assume that they didn't want to get too "involved". Doesn't hurt to learn extra, though!

Comment: @SkeletonBow The second method is known as the root test, and specifically for a power series, it can provide the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Your limit is $|b||x|$.

if this limit is $<1$
which is equivalent to

$|x|<\frac{1}{|b|}$,

then the series is convergent.

and if this limit is $>1$ which means

$|x|>\frac{1}{|b|}$, it diverges.

So, the radius of convergence is

$$\frac{1}{|b|}$$